# Зачем передавать Looper в Handler?

Tags: java, android

В офф документации очень коротко описано о том, что такое `Looper`.

Можете объяснить что это и зачем его передавать в `Handler`

Как в этом примере

```
new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
```

Или вот еще один пример, в чем разница выполнения этих `Hendler`

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Execute some task
                }
            });

new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Execute some task
                }
            });
```

При чем информации и примеров использования `Looper` как параметра очень мало и не понятно, толи из-за того, что это очень редко используется толи из-за того, что мало кто понимает как этим пользоваться...

Реализация `Handler` в `Thread`

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
  public Handler mHandler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
}
```

Comment: [рекомендую](https://habrahabr.ru/post/142256/)

Comment: @iksuy Не совсем было понятно на, что в этой статье нужно было обратить внимание...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Looper` - это что-то вроде фонового потока, который работает постоянно, не завершаясь. Чтобы передать в этот фоновый поток выполнение какой-либо операции, используется `Handler`.

Если создавать `Handler`, не передавая в него `Looper`, то `Looper` возьмется из того потока, в котором вызывается конструктор `Handler()`, при условии, что этот родительский поток является `HandlerThread`.

Поток UI в Android является как раз таким потоком-лупером. Используя `Handler`, можно передавать в UI поток выполнение определенных операций вызовом метода `post(Runnable)`. Естественно, не стоит надеяться, что тело метода `run()` выполнется в момент вызова метода `post`.

В Вашем примере `mBackgroundThread` является наследником `HandlerThread`, следовательно имеет `Looper`.

Разницы во втором Вашем блоке кода никакой нет, если оба конструктора `Handler()` вызываются из UI - потока.

Comment: Значит если я правильно понял `Looper` - это всегда UI поток и передавать его в конструктор `Handler` нужно в том случае если выполняется что то в `background` и для того, чтоб вывести этот `background` в UI поток нужно написать `Handler(contexte.getLooper())` так? Это что то вроде `runOnUiThread()` в данном случае?

Comment: Нет. UI-поток - это пример потока-лупера. Когда происходит создание `Handler()`, происходит его связывание с лупером, который передается в консрукторе, либо с лупером, который находится в текущем потоке, в котором мы вызываем конструктор `Handler()`. Если вдруг, я в обычном потоке создам Handler, не передав ему Looper, то при попытке запостить действие, получу эксепшн. `runOnUiThread` это и есть отправка действия с помощью `Handler`, связанного с UI-лупером.

Comment: Значит `Looper` это конкретный поток конкретного `thread` ? Если я беру его на UI то это будет поток UI, если я беру его на `background` потоке, то он даст мне как раз этот `background` поток, так?

Comment: Ну и тогда если я правильно понимаю то вот такая конструкция будет уместна `new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() ` если я допустим из `CallBack` возвращаю значение из `background` которое мне нужно установить в UI , так? Или в каком случае я могу применить такую конструкцию с передачей mainLoop в конструктор handler?

Comment: Предпоследний комментарий - нет, а последний - верный. Есть обычные `Thread`, а есть `HandlerThread`. У обычных потоков нет `Looper`. UI-поток имеет `Looper`. Вы изучили подробно статью, которую скинул @iksui? Там довольно грамотно описывается разница. Есть еще статья: https://xakep.ru/2016/06/01/android-multithreading-1/

Comment: А можете еще подсказать, что значит такая конструкция `new Handler(Looper.myLooper());` - это в методе `onCreate()` . ? Что это за `myLooper()`?

Comment: Если ты вызываешь этот метод находясь в потоке с лупером, то этот метод вернет этот самый лупер текущего потока. Например, вызвав этот метод в UI потоке, вернется лупер из UI потока, то есть mainLooper

Comment: аа ясно вроде, если я правильно понял , то обычные обьекты не имееют лупера, следовательно если сделать создание такого хендлера в конструкторе обчного обьекта то, что получит хендлер?

Comment: Не объекта, а потока. Если создать в обычном потоке, то ничего не получит, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: ок, а каждый новый поток содержит лупер? Если я создаю `new Thread()` то у него будет совой лупер?

Comment: Читайте внимательно выше о типах потоков

Comment: Ну вот я добавил в вопрос кусок кода и согласно этому я так понимаю, что каждый `Thread` имеет свой `Looper`

Comment: Таким способом - да. Но не каждый Thread имеет лупер.

Comment: А какой не имеет?

Comment: Обычный Thread не имеет лупера

Comment: )) Блин, ну я не пойму чем этот `new Thread()` отличается от обычного?)

Comment: new Thread() это обычный. Если в его методе run() создаешь лупер или твой класс-поток наследуется от HandlerThread, то это уже поток с лупером.